# overrides in css Regardless of the order in file

Tags: html, css

I have input text

```
<input type="text" class="name">
```

Can someone explain why this ccs role

```
   input[type="text"], input[type="search"], input[type="password"] {

        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

override

```
.name{background:yellow}
```

Regardless of the order(who came first) in the css file.

but in case I Specifies the name of the father's class the override is the opposite

for example

```
.form .name {
  background:yellow

}
```

override this

```
 input[type="text"], input[type="search"], input[type="password"] {

        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;

}
```

thanks
Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like this rule (quote from this [**wonderful article**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)) for measuring selector specificity:

> Count the number of ID attributes in the selector (`= a`). Count the
>   number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (`= b`).
>   Count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector
>   (`= c`). Concatenating the three numbers `a-b-c` gives the specificity

For `.name` selector, it's just `0-1-0` - just a single classname.

For `.form .name`, it's `0-2-0` - two classnames.

For `input[type="text"]`, it's `0-1-1`, as an attribute selector is combined with the element name. Obviously, it's more specific than `0-1-0`, but less than `0-2-0`. )

Comment: As a Star Wars fan I've always been partial to this [CSS specificity guide](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).